# Bytebuddy loaded class not found

Tags: byte-buddy

I am trying to build a class that holds a reference to another class object through a field. Something like this:

```
Class A extends Parent {private B b;}

Class B extends Child {private String s;}
```

I am able to make and load Class B first, instantiate its object and set it to the field in class A by intercepting A's constructor.

However, when I try to load the unloaded type A it throws class not found exception for type B even though its already loaded.
I hope this is possible to do with bytebuddy. If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the implementation:

```
private static final ClassLoader SYSTEM_CLASS_LOADER = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

public Class<? extends Parent> generateParentClass(ParentConfig config) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Class<? extends Child>> fieldMap = config.getChildren().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(ChildConfig::getName, this::generateChildClass));

    Implementation.Composable constructorInterceptor = MethodCall.invoke(Parent.class.getConstructor());
    for(Map.Entry<String, Class<? extends Child>> entry : fieldMap.entrySet()) {
        Child child = entry.getValue().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        constructorInterceptor = constructorInterceptor.andThen(FieldAccessor.ofField(entry.getKey()).setsReference(child));
    }

    DynamicType.Builder<Parent> typeBuilder = new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(Parent.class)
            .name(Parent.class.getPackageName() + "." + config.getType())
            .annotateType(Parent.class.getAnnotations())
            .constructor(any())
            .intercept(constructorInterceptor);

    for(Map.Entry<String, Class<? extends Child>> entry : fieldMap.entrySet())
        typeBuilder = typeBuilder.defineField(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), Modifier.PRIVATE);

    DynamicType.Unloaded<Parent> unloadedType = typeBuilder.make();
    return unloadedType.load(SYSTEM_CLASS_LOADER).getLoaded(); //ClassNotFoundException for Type Child
}

private Class<? extends Child> generateChildClass(ChildConfig config) {
    DynamicType.Builder<Child> typeBuilder = new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(Child.class)
            .name(Child.class.getPackageName() + "." + config.getName())
            .annotateType(Child.class.getAnnotations());

    for(Attribute attribute : config.getAttributes())
        typeBuilder = typeBuilder.defineField(attribute.getName(), attribute.getTypeClass(), Modifier.PRIVATE);

    DynamicType.Unloaded<Child> unloadedType = typeBuilder.make();
    return unloadedType.load(SYSTEM_CLASS_LOADER).getLoaded();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run `unloadedType.load(SYSTEM_CLASS_LOADER)`, you create a new class loader. All types that are loaded within this class loader are not visible to other classes outside of it. What you can do is to merge two *unloadedType* values and load them together into the same class loader. Types are still available via `TypeDescription`s. Alternatively, you can define a custom `ClassLoadingStrategy` or use a default strategy that uses injection via unsafe or via a method handle lookup (Java 9+). The *load* method accepts it as its second argument.